# Sendfile on a character device file descriptor

Tags: c, linux, linux-device-driver

I have an FPGA on a SoC that generates and streams continuously a huge amount of data that is retrieved through dma operations and put in RAM. Then it has to be sent to the network through an ethernet port with a bitrate approaching a gigabit/s.
In order to handle efficiently the big amount of data to transfer, I have decided to use the sendfile system call from userspace. As sendfile uses the splice mechanism, my device driver supports splice operations.

Unfortunately, sendfile returns -EINVAL when the input file descriptor is my character device file backed by my driver. After further investigation, it seems that the linux kernel refuses any file of type other than regular or block. That's what the linux kernel source seems to say [here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.1.12/source/fs/splice.c#L1166) :

```
/*
 * We require the input being a regular file, as we don't want to
 * randomly drop data for eg socket -> socket splicing. Use the
 * piped splicing for that!
 */
i_mode = file_inode(in)->i_mode;
if (unlikely(!S_ISREG(i_mode) && !S_ISBLK(i_mode)))
    return -EINVAL;
```

The manpage for sendfile(2) seems to tell the same :

> The in_fd argument must correspond to a file which supports mmap(2)-like operations (i.e., it cannot be a socket).

Why is that ? I don't understand quite well the technical reason which forbid this case, that is using sendfile on a character device file descriptor as input.

Comment: The manpage also says: "The Linux-specific splice(2) call supports transferring data between arbitrary files (e.g., a pair of sockets)." <- Maybe worth a try?

Comment: @Ctx Will try that in the mean time, thank you. What i'm worried about though is the number of context switches when calling splice in userspace given the small size of the pipes on which we splice.

Comment: For splice(2) the man page says one of the file descriptors must refer to a pipe. The code in do_splice() (in "fs/splice.c") confirms that.